# Is it possible to send a application.properties file in arguments through a Jar file?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar, application.properties

I have a Springboot project and I know I can send a application.properties file as a argument, but is this possible using a jar file?

I built my jar file using maven  and in my application I have this piece of code that runs the programm if the user sent the argument run.

Is there any method that allows me to set the application properties if I receive it through argument? Or does the override of the file happens automatically as it does when I use the command
`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.config.location=your.properties`

```
if (args[0].equals("run")) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);
            int exitCode = SpringApplication.exit(ctx, () -> 0);
            System.exit(exitCode);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jar you can either pass one of the properties or the complete or its location as beow.

we can  configure the location directly in the command line:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config/jdbc.properties
```

We can also pass a folder location where the application will search for the file:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.name=application,jdbc --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config
```

And, an alternative approach is running the Spring Boot application through the Maven plugin. There, we can use a -D parameter:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.config.location="file:///Users/home/jdbc.properties"
```

Comment: This might seem a stupid question, but what if while using the folder approach the specified folder has more than one file?

Comment: have a look 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html